# Explicit Computation of Maps of Completed Local Rings of Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, localization

I would like to see explicitly on the level of completed local rings, how for curves Geometric Frobenius looks differently than a separable cover ramified at a point.

In other words, let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $2$ and consider the following inclusion maps:

1. $k[x] \to k[x,y]/(y^2-x)$
2. $k[x] \to k[x,y]/(y^2-x+yx)$

After localizing at $(x)$ and $(x,y)$ respectively, how can I compute the induced maps of completed local rings and see that these maps are non-isomorphic but are isomorphic if the characteristic of $k$ is different from $2$? This must hold due to algebraic geometry but I would like to see this result more elementary.

I know that the completion will always be of the form $k[[z]]$, but I cannot keep track of the morphisms. Is there an algorithm of computing completed local rings and induced maps between them in general? At least in the version that I know it, Cohen Structure Theorem is not constructive enough for explicit computations.

Comment: The completions of $k[x],k[x,y]/(x-y^2),k[x,y]/((1-y)x-y^2)$ are 

$k[[x]],k[[y]], k[[y]]$ respectively

with $x$ mapped either to $y^2$ or to $\frac{y^2}{1-y}$. If the characteristic is not $2$ then $1-y=(1+yf(y))^2$ so that $k[[y]] = k[[ \frac{y}{1+yf(y)}]]$ and in both case the map is the natural embedding $k[[x]]\to k[[x^{1/2}]]$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you explain how you made this computation or give a reference where I can learn about it? Also what is f?

Comment: $f$ is some element of $k[[y]]$. Which step is unclear to you?

Comment: So is it true that for a variety with coordinate ring $k[X_1, \dots, X_N]/I$ the completed local ring at the origin is simply $k[[X_1, \dots, X_N]]/I$ but on the level of power series there are simply more morphisms, so things get isomorphic?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$